# What a buffer looks like on the stack

Tags: c, arrays, stack, int, buffer

When you reserve a buffer on the stack in c. In what order are the elements stored?

Example:

```
char buf[4];
```

Let's say the stack looks like this now:

```
return addr
basepointer
buf
buf
buf
buf <-stack pointer points here
```

And then you do:

```
myArray[0]=6;
```

Does the stack look like:

```
return addr
basepointer
buf
buf
buf
6 <-stack pointer points here
```

or like:

```
return addr
basepointer
6
buf
buf
buf <-stack pointer points here
```

And what if you have an int array and store an int in one of the array indexes. Will the first byte of the int be on the bottom (near the stack pointer) or on the top (nearer to the basepointer)?

Comment: This question isn't answerable. All of those are *implementation details* of *particular compilers*. Why do you want to know this stuff? Let the compiler lay out the stack frame as it sees fit.

Comment: I have an assignment where we need to do a bufferoverflow on a given binary. It is relevant for the assignment, but appearently it depends on the compiler. I now discovered that my buffer was not on the address that I assumed it was at. I tested it now and found my answer for this particular binary. thanks.

Comment: There is in fact no requirement that the locals be put on the stack at all. If you're not taking their addresses then they can be enregistered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general answer for this, it's up to the compiler to decide how to lay out the variables. Different compilers can make different choices, and the same compiler with different compilation flags can also lead to different choices. It's even possible (though not generally likely nor desired) for the same compiler and flags to produce different results from different compilations.